# ElasticSearch an edgeNGram for autocomplete\typeahead, is my search_analyzer being ignored

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've got three documents with a "userName" field:

- 'briandilley'
- 'briangumble'
- 'briangriffen'

when i search for 'brian' i get all three back as expected, but when i search for 'briandilley' i still get all three back.  The analyze API is telling me that it's using the ngram filter on my search string, but i'm not sure why.  here's my setup:

**index settings:**

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "username_index": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "username_ngram"]
            },
            "username_search": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "username_ngram": {
                "type": "edgeNGram",
                "side" : "front",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 15
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**mapping:**

```
{
    "user_follow": {

        "properties": {
            "targetId": { "type": "string", "store": true },
            "followerId": { "type": "string", "store": true },
            "dateUpdated": { "type": "date", "store": true },

            "userName": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "userName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index_analyzer": "username_index",
                        "search_analyzer": "username_search"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**search:**

```
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 50,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
                "field" : {
                    "targetId" : "51888c1b04a6a214e26a4009"
                }
            }, {
                "match" : {
                    "userName.autocomplete" : {
                        "query" : "brian",
                        "type" : "boolean"
                    }
                }
            } ]
        }
    },
    "fields" : "followerId"
}
```

I've tried matchQuery, matchPhraseQuery, textQuery and termQuery (java DSL api) and i get the same results every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you're not doing exactly what you think you're doing. This is why it is useful to present an actual test case with full `curl` statements, rather than abbreviating it.

Your example above works for me (slightly modified):

Create the index with settings and mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "mappings" : {
     "test" : {
        "properties" : {
           "userName" : {
              "fields" : {
                 "autocomplete" : {
                    "search_analyzer" : "username_search",
                    "index_analyzer" : "username_index",
                    "type" : "string"
                 },
                 "userName" : {
                    "index" : "not_analyzed",
                    "type" : "string"
                 }
              },
              "type" : "multi_field"
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "settings" : {
     "analysis" : {
        "filter" : {
           "username_ngram" : {
              "max_gram" : 15,
              "min_gram" : 1,
              "type" : "edge_ngram"
           }
        },
        "analyzer" : {
           "username_index" : {
              "filter" : [
                 "lowercase",
                 "username_ngram"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
           },
           "username_search" : {
              "filter" : [
                 "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
'
```

Index some data:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '{
  "userName" : "briangriffen"
}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "userName" : "brianlilley"
}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "userName" : "briangumble"
}
'
```

A search for `brian` finds all documents:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '{
  "query" : {
     "match" : {
        "userName.autocomplete" : "brian"
     }
  }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "userName" : "briangriffen"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.1486337,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "AWzezvEFRIykOAr75QbtcQ",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "userName" : "briangumble"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.1486337,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "qIABuMOiTyuxLOiFOzcURg",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "userName" : "brianlilley"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.076713204,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "fGgTITKvR6GJXI_cqA4Vzg",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.1486337,
#       "total" : 3
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 8
# }
```

A search for `brianlilley` finds just that document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "query" : {
     "match" : {
        "userName.autocomplete" : "brianlilley"
     }
  }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "userName" : "brianlilley"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.076713204,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "fGgTITKvR6GJXI_cqA4Vzg",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.076713204,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 4
# }
```

Comment: I'm doing this in a java unit test - so that's why there aren't any CURL statements (using the in memory client).

Comment: Well, chances are you are doing something wrong there then. By reproducing it as curl, you can see if you can recreate the problem. If you can't, then the problem is in your Java code. (I mean produce the curl statements manually, which you can do)

Comment: You were right - i was indexing the target's username instead of the follower's username.  Basically bad indexing on my part.  I've marked your answer as the correct one since you helped lead me to what the real problem was.