# Simple autocomplete in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a simple autocomplete in Elasticsearch?

I need to enter a beginning of a word into search input and I want elasticsearch to find all words starting with it. I want Elasticsearch to search in all fields in my type (`Post` containing `Title`, `Body`, `Tags`).

In [this example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example#part-5-suggestions) I need to add special suggest fields i.e. `TitleSuggest`, `BodySuggest` etc. and specify input and output logic.

It also returns a list of `Posts` while I just need words.

Comment: Have you looked into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411963/elasticsearch-an-edgengram-for-autocomplete-typeahead-is-my-search-analyzer-bei

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand i will do like this :

```
 {
    "query" : {
        "dis_max" : {
            "tie_breaker" : 0,
            "boost" : 1,
            "queries" : [{
                    "wildcard" : {
                        "title" : "searchme*"
                    }
                }, {
                    "wildcard"
                     : {
                        "body" : "searchme*"
                    }
                }, {
                    "wildcard" : {
                        "tags" : "searchme*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "title" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "title",
                "size" : 10
            }
        },
        "body" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "body",
                "size" : 10
            }
        },
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tags",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

It search all the datas begining with "searchme" in the fields :  title, body, tags and return a list of 10 terms for each.

there is also autocomplete in elastic but i never use it yet :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

Answer (score 0):

According to one post from elastic issue tracker, maybe you should try query like this:

```
.Query(q => 
  q.Text(tq => tq                                              
    .OnField(t => t.MyField1.Suffix("autocomplete"))
    .QueryString(searchString)
  )                    
  && q.Text(tq => tq                                              
    .OnField(t => t.MyField2.Suffix("autocomplete"))
    .QueryString(searchString)
  )    
)
```

more info:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/456